# How permanent is data stored in Ethereum?

Tags: nodes, chaindata, immutability

Does it all depend on the availability of nodes? What if say there's 1 node left in Ethereum, will that node contains the entire blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each node connected in the blockchain contains a copy of the entire chain in which consensus is held. With Ethereum, these nodes are called validators. The less validators there are, the less copies of the blockchain there are and less validators keeps the consensus.
If only one validator exists, this validator controls the entire chain, which obviously leads to centrilization and would defeat the whole purpose of the blockchain.

As with how permanently data is stored on the blockchain, this then leads to how 'permanent' this validator stays on the chain. If this validator decides to 'disconnect' all data will not neccesarily be lost as it could be backed up or stored somewhere else. The only thing which will then occur is the chain will not add any more data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every node contains a complete copy of the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

I came into this question looking for technical answers on the permanency of data stored on Ethereum. If it helps, here's my 2023 findings:

Vitalik himself talks about this while discusing sharding. In specific, he notes (although, he differentiates between Data Retrievability and Data Availability, which I find hard to discern):

> A necessary co-requisite to increasing data space is removing the
> property that the Ethereum core protocol is responsible for
> permanently maintaining all of the data that it comes to consensus on.
> The amount of data is simply too large to require this. For example:
>
> - EIP 4488 leads to a theoretical maximum chain size of ~1,262,861 bytes per 12 sec slot, or ~3.0 TB per year, though in practice
>   ~250-1000 GB per year is more likely especially at the beginning
> - 4 shards (1 MB per slot) adds an additional (virtually guaranteed) ~2.5 TB per year
> - 64 shards (16 MB per slot) leads to a total (virtually guaranteed) ~40 TB storage per year
>
> Most users’ hard drives are between 256 GB and 2 TB in size, and 1 TB
> seems like the median. An internal poll in a group of blockchain
> researchers:
>
> This means that users can afford to run a node today, but could not if
> any part of this roadmap is implemented without further modification.
> Much larger drives are available, but users would have to go out of
> their way to buy them, significantly increasing the complexity of
> running a node. The leading solution to this is EIP 4444, which
> removes node operators’ responsibility to store blocks or receipts
> older than 1 year. In the context of sharding, this period will likely
> be shortened further, and nodes would only be responsible for the
> shards on the subnets that they are actively participating in.
>
> This leaves open the question: if the Ethereum core protocol will not
> store this data, who will?
>
> First of all, it’s important to remember that even with sharding, the
> amount of data will not be that large. Yes, 40 TB per year is out of
> reach of individuals running “default” consumer hardware (in fact,
> even 1 TB per year is). However, it’s well within the reach of a
> dedicated single individual willing to put some resources and work
> into storing the data. Here is a 48 TB HDD for $1729 and here is 14 TB
> for ~$420. Someone running a single 32 ETH validator slot could pay to
> store the entire post-sharding chain out of staking rewards. So the
> case where literally no one will store some historical data of some
> shard to the point that it becomes completely lost to humanity seems
> impossible.

Source on the ethereum blog, here: https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/data_sharding_roadmap#Who-would-store-historical-data-under-sharding